# How do you set default attributes in an angular element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several similar repetitive angular elements.

For example:

```
<div  ui-grid="myUIGrid" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-selection  ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-save-state ui-grid-resize-columns>
...
</div>
```

Is there anyway that automatically sets these attributes anytime there is an attribute named `ui-grid` ?

For example:

```
<div  ui-grid="myUIGrid">
...
</div>
```

Will automatically load 
`ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-selection  ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-save-state ui-grid-resize-columns` into that element.

Answer (score 2):

Set a directive on the `ui-grid` attribute and have the directive add additional attributes anytime `ui-grid` is applied to an element.

```
myApp.directive('uiGrid', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.attr('ui-grid-auto-resize', '');
            // More attributes
        }
    }
});
```